# Effect of metal colander on jerky meat post-marinade

Tags: marinade, jerky

I make a lot of beef jerky. I always marinade in for at least a day in a Ziploc bag. After marinade, I leave it in a colander for several hours to drain and speed up drying. The colander I've always used for this is just a cheap metal one from a garage sale. I know you're not supposed to marinate meat in a metal container, and lately have been wondering if the time in the colander is having any effect on my jerky. I've never noticed any metallic taste or discoloration. What are the odds the colander is effecting the jerky in some way?

Comment: What sort of "metal" is it... can you tell? Is it lined with anything or is it bare metal?

Comment: It's bare metal, and sort of looks like aluminum, but can't be sure.

Comment: On second thought, it has to be stainless steel. Aluminum wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stainless steel, ceramics, and glass are considered "non-reactive" in the kitchen, while vessels made from aluminum, copper, iron, and steel are considered "reactive".  The latter category are reactive with acidic and alkaline foods (lemon and tomato, for example).  The result is that these foods can take on a metallic taste.

If you have not noticed any off-taste, you are probably using stainless.